# understanding CalcTreeWidth in bitcoin Merkle tree implementation

Tags: c++, merkle-tree

I'm trying to understand this bitshifting function:

```
/** helper function to efficiently calculate the number of nodes at given height in the merkle tree */
    unsigned int CalcTreeWidth(int height) const {
        return (nTransactions+(1 << height)-1) >> height;
    }
```

I tried running the function by hand and I can see that it produces correct result but I don't get it, I understand that the part : `(1 << height)-1)` basically sets `N=height` bits to 1, what I don't understand is the next part.

Why does adding the number of leafs and shifting right height times result in the number of node on that level?

Comment: I think it's just doing nTransactions>>height but rounding up instead of rounding down

Comment: The actually makes a lot of sense, it looks like it's doing /2 height times.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing `nTransactions >> height` but rounding up instead of rounding down.

`nTransactions >> height` is `nTransactions / (1 << height)`. By adding `(1 << height) - 1` we make it so that if `nTransactions` isn't an exact multiple of `1 << height` then the result is 1 greater.